# difference between printf() and std::cout with respect to pointers

Tags: c++, c, pointers, printf, cout

I am new to pointers and i cant figure out one simple thing.

```
   int main ()
{
    char *str1="pointer";
    printf("%p \n", str1);
    cout << str1<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output is as follows :

```
0000000000409001
pointer
```

Could someone please explain me the difference here. 
why isnt cout printing the memory address ? how can i make cout print the address of str1?

Comment: The difference here is caused by the format specifier (`%p`) you have provided `printf`.

Comment: While the torrent takes place below, can you elaborate on your point of confusion? It is somewhat clear you already know what `%p` does for `printf`.  Is your point of confusion why `std::cout << str` does *not* print the pointer value, and instead prints the string content ? If so, it is due to *operator overloading* on output streams, where the library-provided overload for a rhs `char*` will drill into the string and actually print the content rather than just the address.

Comment: Short answer: In C++, when you use `<<` and `cout` to print something, you get a default format that's intended to be maximally useful and convenient.  For `int` you get something like `%d`.  For `char *` you get something like `%s`.  To get something more like `%p`, see the answer from @tmlen below.

Comment: @SteveSummit thank you so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The format specifier `%p` prints a `void *`, (untrue: so the `char *` is implicitly converted to `void *`) the `char *` is converted to `void *` before printing. (But this is actually undefined behavior, see comments. The correct way to do that would be `printf("%p", (void *) str1);`) The corresponding C++ code would be `std::cout << (void *) str1 << '\n';`.

The code `std::cout << str1;` prints `str1` as null terminated string. The corresponding C-code would be `printf('%s', str1);`

Comment: You need to explicitly cast pointers to `void *` when passing them to a `%p` format in order to avoid undefined behavior, btw.

Comment: "char * is implicitly converted to void * before printing" --> In C, **no** implicit conversion occurred.  `char *` and `void*` happen to have then same encoding.   Better to explicitly convert with a `void *` cast as per @Shawn.

Answer (score 3):

A pointer is an address to a location in memory.

`"pointer"` is a C-string in memory, 8 bytes for the letters and a terminating NULL byte. `str1` is a pointer to the byte of the first letter `'p'`.

---

`printf("%p", str1)` prints the value of the pointer itself, that is the memory address (in this case `0000000000409001`).

`printf("%s", str1)` would print `pointer`, the content of the C-string at location `str1`.

---

`cout << str1 << endl` also prints the content of the C-string. This is the default behavior for pointer of type `char*` because they are usually strings.

`cout << static_cast<void*>(str1) << endl` would print the address of the pointer again.

Comment: I think it wouldn't hurt to also note that using &str instead of (void*)str would print out the address of the pointer itself, and not the address of the first element (the 'p' in "pointer").

Answer (score 1):

a char* is a pointer to the beginning of an array of characters.

`cout` "recognizes" a char* and treats it like a string.

<strike>You are explicitly telling printf() to print out the decimal representation of a pointer address with the %p formatter.</strike>

You are explicitly telling printf() to print out **a representation** of the pointer address with the %p formatter.

EDIT: edited for accuracy based on comment

Comment: Rather than "print out the decimal representation" is more like "print out the some representation, perhaps hexadecimal "

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Thanks for the comment. Edited for accuracy.